# What's the most recommended SSD for a Lenovo thinkpad x220?

Tags: ssd

I want to upgrade my Lenovo [Thinkpad x220](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd015812) with an SSD, but I'm not sure how much storage capacity I should target, maybe around 200-300 GB should be sufficient.

What product do you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: Hello there. You technically have dozens of choices. What is your budget? Where do you intend to buy the SSD from?

Comment: @NatsuKage Hi, I understand there are a lot of them to choose from, and I'll buy it wherever. Max 100$. Thank you.

Comment: I meant to ask for your location? Shipping cost can be quite prohibitive nowadays. As Evan said, Samsung and Crucial are quite good, but their price is sometimes higher for nothing at some locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Samsung SSDs tend to have the best reputation. Crucial is a close second. I would recommend the [Samsung 860 EVO 250GB 2.5" SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07864WMK8). After the 860 EVO, I would recommend the [Crucial MX 500 250GB SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0764WCXCV).

Comment: I have the 500GB Crucial MX500 and would NOT recommend it.  It has a longstanding, very annoying and life-reducing FW bug.  https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/mx500-ssd-smart-errors.53779/post-306464 or google for "MX500 pending sector bug".  Crucial has apparently done nothing to fix this mess.  Furthermore, the last FW update was so botched they pulled it completely https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/izsi80/crucial_mx500_ssd_firmware_wont_update_via/  Nutshell: Crucial has some very serious quality issues and is not addressing them (or worse its engineers are subpar and unable to).

Answer (score 0):

Performance will be limited by the [SATA-II drive interface](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd015812) designed for the original HDD, so spending extra money on high performance SSDs would be a waste.

The aforementioned Samsung and Crucial SSDs do have a good reputation. If you are buying to use it with Windows, make sure the manufacturer includes a free [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) diagnostic app to work with your version of Windows.